# Reutilização de código JS de um bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: javascript

Possuo um bootstrap-datepicker com o seguinte JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() 
        {
            var dataIni = $("#calendarioIni");
            var dataFim = $("#calendarioFim");

            $('#calendarioIni').datepicker({
                startDate: '01/01/1998', 
                endDate: '31/12/1998', 
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',

            });

            $('#calendarioFim').datepicker({
                startDate: '01/01/1998',
                endDate: '31/12/1998', 
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',

            });
 });
```

Porém irei utiliza-lo em várias páginas no meu projeto, como poderia fazer a reutilização de código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se em todas as páginas o id do elemento for o mesmo você pode simplesmente adicionar esse trecho de código em um .js e importa-lo em todas as páginas assim quando você quiser fazer qualquer alteração só modificar o .js

Ficaria algo desse tipo :

```
<script src="seu-arquivo.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

Dentro do  de suas páginas .html

Comment: seria ideal eu criar um .js somente para colocar ele?

Comment: Não necessariamente. Você pode aproveitar esse js para colocar códigos que "se repetem" na maioria das páginas tendo em vista ter uma manutenção mais tranquila.

Comment: bom, por enquanto somente esse datepicker que vai repetir mesmo...

Comment: o código seria exatamente igual? inclusive essa parte: $(document).ready(function()? acho que é só o function que fica né?

Comment: Esse ready() no document quer dizer, após o carregamento do mesmo, ao meu ponto de vista pode continuar assim.